# How can I add to the $PATH in the DDEV web container? (for drush, for example)

Tags: ddev

I need an additional directory to appear in my $PATH in the ddev web container, for example, /var/www/html/bin, and I need it to show up not just when I `ddev ssh` (which could be done with ~/.homeadditions/.bashrc) but also when I use `ddev exec`. This came to a head with ddev v1.17, where drush launcher was removed from the web container and so `ddev exec drush` and `ddev drush` no longer found the drush command in my nonstandard composer install.

Answer (score 4):

Edited for DDEV v1.19+:

There's a new and efficient/flexible way to add to the $PATH now.

```sh
mkdir -p .ddev/homeadditions/.bashrc.d
cd .ddev/homeadditions/bashrc.d
```

then just edit a file named `path.sh` (name isn't important) and add to it something that changes the $PATH, for example `export PATH=$PATH:/var/www/html/somewhereelse/vendor/bin`

See [docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/customization-extendibility/#altering-the-in-container-path).

--------- Original answer below ------------

There are at least two ways to extend the $PATH in the web container. Here we'll add `/var/www/html/something` to the standard $PATH.

Either of these options will work:

- Mount a replacement commandline-addons.bashrc with a docker-compose.path.yaml:

.ddev/docker-compose.path.yaml:

```yaml
version: '3.6'
#ddev-generated
services:
  web:
    volumes:
      - ./commandline-addons.bashrc:/etc/bashrc/commandline-addons.bashrc
```

.ddev/commandline-addons.bashrc:

```sh
export PATH="$PATH:/var/www/html/vendor/bin:/var/www/html/something"
```

- Add /editthe commandline-addons.bashrc in a .ddev/web-build/Dockerfile. (If you use this option, the custom Dockerfile overrides `webimage_extra_packages` in .ddev/config.yaml, so you'll have to use [workarounds in docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/customizing-images/#adding-extra-dockerfiles-for-webimage-and-dbimage))

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM $BASE_IMAGE
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/var/www/html/vendor/bin:/var/www/html/something"' >/etc/bashrc/commandline-addons.bashrc
```

Both of these options require a `ddev restart` after adding them.

Comment: Just to point out that if your docroot is something like `xxx/web` then you need to modify the path
`RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/var/www/html/xxx/vendor/bin:/var/www/html/bin"' > /etc/bashrc/commandline-addons.bashrc`

Comment: Most projects have the vendor in the project root (so /var/www/html/vendor), NOT the docroot (/var/www/html/docroot/vendor)

I'll also update because in v1.17.1, /var/www/html/bin is already added to the default PATH